# Using representValue() in Python Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to use the represent value from a field of a feature.

I tried something like this but I get no result:

```py
valuerepresent = QgsListFieldFormatter().representValue(layer=currentMapLayer,
                                                        fieldIndex=fieldidx,
                                                        config={},
                                                        cache=None,
                                                        value=value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm clearly not familiar with this particular class `QgsListFieldFormatter` in the API. You should look at Python official test file [test_qgsfieldformatters.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsfieldformatters.py) to sort out what you want.